# how to show the entry completion popup as soon as the text field has focus in gtk+ 3.2?

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I have a Gtk Entry that uses a Entry Completion object. I have set it up to an extent. If I enter the `minimum key length` number of characters the completion popup shows me available choices. So far so good.

Now what I want is that the text field should show the completion popup even it is empty, as soon as it has focus. Even if set the completion object's `minimum key length` to `0`, the completion popup will not immediately appear as soon as the text field has focus. It will, however, appear if I enter something then delete it, leaving the text field empty.

My real goal is to select an item from a predefined list of choices, quickly, using the keyboard. What I did was to use a Gtk Entry attached to an Entry Completion Object which uses a List Store. Any alternatives are most welcome...

I am using gtkmm/Glade for doing my work. Please tell me if I need to add anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select from a list of predefined choices you'd probably be better using a [combo box](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1ComboBox.html) instead of a entry.